# Installation ubuntu 12.04.64 bit on notebook toshiba: no root file system is defined. No partitions recognized

Tags: installation

Still with no solution on installing Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS on my Toshiba notebook U945, alongside windows 8 pre/installed.
I Followed forum indications (create a new partition from windows 8, disabled Secure root)
I also checked from gparted on "try ubuntu" mode, and it did recognize all partitions.
Previously i checked the ubuntu version i downloaded and confirmed it is not corrupted.

You can see the message it appears on my screen when trying to install ubuntu, in this web site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKzJh.jpg.

Any other suggestion?  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your HDD is not recognized. Try to disable features like FastBoot in BIOS.